# Unable to Create A Link Service to Sharepoint Onlist List with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can somoene confirm that the reason I'm unable to create a Link Service or connection to Sharepoint Online is because I don't have the necessary permissions to SharePoint Online List. And if that is the case when needs to be done on SharePoint Online List to grant the necessary permissions?
[image]

I forgot to mention that when I try to connect from a different instance of Data Factory I get a slightly different error message:

> Failed to get metadata of odata service, please check if service url
> and credential is correct and your application has permission to the
> resource. Expected status code: 200, actual status code: Forbidden,
> response is :  <!DOCTYPE html
> PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the above scenario in my environment and got the same error.

[image]

To resolve this error, we need to grant SharePoint Online site permission to your Service principal.

To do that, I followed this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list-copy-activity#prerequisites) and granted the permissions in this URL `https://[your_site_url]/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`.

[image]

Give the **App Id of service principal**, any title and for App Domain and Redirect URL refer the same documentation which had explanation on those.

I have give the App Domain as `<oragnization>.sharepoint.com` and the Redirect URL is the display of page of sharepoint which lists the content of my site.

**Ex:** `https://<oraganization>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site_name>/Lists/<list_name>/AllItems.aspx`

After granting the permission, I am able to create the linked service successfully.

[image]

Coming to your first error, it might be due to the Data factory roles and permissions. Check the roles between your first ADF and second ADF. I have Contributor role in my ADF.